# How to restrict access to ASP.NET's Website Admin Tool?

Tags: asp.net, web, administration

Is there a way to change the url, or change some config setting that would allow only certain people to find/hit the WAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the admin tool you see in visual studio?  The site/tool itself doesn't actually exist anywhere but inside studio.  All it does is provide a user-friendly way of managing some values in your database and your web.config file.

If you want to restrict access to what the admin tool actually does, restrict access to the database.  You can also look at restricting who has write permissions to your web.config in whatever you're using for source control.  Restricting access to source in the first place is an entirely different topic, but one to consider if you haven't already done so...

Comment: Well, that settles it. It looked like the tool was running on the server, similar to glassfish's admin console.

Comment: Nope, it's all internal on VS's Cassini server.  Same deal as when you debug a site that isn't hosted on IIS.